# Hudson UI plugin to build from main page

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins

Is there Hudson plugin to start build from main page instead of visiting job's page to click 'build' in it

Comment: This shouldn't need a plugin - click the stopwatches on the right hand side of each job on the index screen to kick off a build.

Answer (score 0):

You can start build from everywhere by url:
http://**YOUR_HUDSON_SERVER:PORT**/job/**YOUR_JOB_NAME**/build?delay=0sec